# Add SVG to HTML and handle events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have this SVG file. which display different svg elements (Circle, Eclipse, Polygon,polyline etc)

and each element has its own ID.

I can add the function (onClick or MouseClicK) when that specific ID is clicked.

Is there any way to add a common function (in JavaScript or Jquery) which respond to click event and tells us from which object (ID) click originates?

So I need:

1. HTML code to add/reference SVG file. Not sure if I use SVG or Object
   tag? Which one works in all browsers?
2. And then JQuery of JavaScript which respond to mouse click on the elements and tell which ID has been clicked?

If you see following SVG it has different circles which has ID e.g. 01, 02, 03 etc.

http://imgh.us/ClockControl.svg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to print the svg directly into the html. This way each SVG Element is a »real member« of the DOM.

```
<html>
    <head>
        …
    </head>
    <body>
        …
        <!-- 
           this stands for the content of »ClockControl.svg« 
           open it in a text editor, copy all the content, beginning at
           <svg and paste it into the html
        -->

        <svg id="your-svg">
            …
            <path id="e1" d="…" />
            …
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next thing is event handling, what could be done something like that (on load):

```
var svg = document.querySelector('svg#your-svg'),
    handlers = {
        'e1' : function(e){ … }
    };
svg.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var c = e.target;
    while (c !== svg) {
        if (c.hasAttribute('id') {
            var id = c.getAttribute('id');

            if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                handlers[id](c);
                break;
            } 
        }
        c = c.parentNode;
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h5rog9ab/1/)

If you are not familiar with all the ways an SVG can inserted into the HTML have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/). The method used in this answer in called »inline SVG«.

Comment: Not working. Where to add "ClockControl.SVG"? does it need to go into d="..."?

Comment: have a look at the fiddle, its running… To strip all the inkscape things from the svg I recommend to use svg cleaner

Comment: Cool! thanks Philipp. Thanks for svg cleaner suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code (just vanilla JavaScript with no use of jQuery), which adds an event listener `click` on every SVG element in your page.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('svg').forEach(function(item){
item.addEventListener('click', function(event){alert('svg clicked was: ' + event.target.id)});
})
```

```css
#circle{
  position:absolute;

}
#rect{
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translate(80px, 80px)
}
```

```html
Click on one of the following SVG shapes.
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <circle id="circle"  cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
   <rect id="rect" width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)">
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to get the id

```js
$('svg').click(function(){
alert('element ID is: '+this.id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="1" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
<svg id="2" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: It will be one SVG file with multiple ID's. I can handle events separately trying to explore if there is a better way!  Also I see there are various ways to add SVG file to HTML... (<object>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img src="image.svg" />, <svg>) which is best way to add? so it shall work in all browsers

Comment: I wrote you a technique to find which id was clicked, of course if you handle each event separately it will take less resources but more work on the code.  Here is a good article about the different formats and their browser support https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/, this are the browsers that support the method i used (HTML5) http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-html5